# Get the list of Outlook Categories from specific Account

Tags: vba, outlook

So I have the following code working, it is a UserForm and basically what it does here is to fill a ComboBox with each Category my Outlook Account has.

However, it only works for main set-up account, and I can't find a way to make it get the categories from a previously selected account (with another combobox).
The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim objNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim objCategory As Category
    Dim strOutput As String

    Set objNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        If objNameSpace.Categories.Count > 0 Then
            For Each objCategory In objNameSpace.Categories
                strOutput = objCategory.Name    
        With Me.ChosenCategory
        .AddItem (strOutput)
        End With     
            Next    
        With Me.ChosenCategory
        .AddItem ("Clear Category")
        End With

        End If

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to specify first which Account do I want it to get the categories from?

Answer (score 0):

Categories are stored in a hidden message with the message class of "IPM.Configuration.CategoryList" in the store's Calendar folder. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) if you go to the shared Calendar folder and click the IMAPIFolder button, then go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

That hidden message can be accessed using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` in the Outlook Object Model.

You can also access the Categories collection in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) using [RDOCategories](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocategories.htm) collection. Redemption exposes  categories both on the session level ([RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Categories` from the default store) and on the store level ([RDOStore2](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOStore2).`Categories`). A shared mailbox can be retrieved from the `RDOSession.Stores` collection (if it is already available in the profile) or opened using `RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox`.

Comment: Hello. It is not a shared mailbox, it's just another Outlook account. I.E. mail1@mail.com has categories "red", "blue" and "white", while mail2@mail.com has "black" and "green". Whenever I populate combobox, it will always bring the 3 categories from mail 1. What I want is to be able to tell VBA which account to get the categories from.

Comment: OK, then you need to open the store that you need to retrieve categories from using the Namespace.Stores collection, call Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar), then use MAPIFolder.GetStorage to read the hidden message used to store the categories. Or you can use Redemotion and its RDOStore2.Categories collection.

Comment: Do you have any specific piece of code which I can use to accomplish that? I'm not really used to VBA Outlook commands yet, still learning many things about it. Thank you

Comment: I don't have ready to run code, sorry. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Where to insert the commands you typed into my code, where it should test if the account is the correct one and then extract categories from that account.