# C# VSTO (COM) Outlook how to get/change other NameSpace?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an Add-in for Outlook to set categories for emails.

1. The user receives an email and needs to add a color category to the email
2. If there is no category, then add a category

Program progress:

```
Outlook.Categories categories = Application.Session.Categories;

Outlook.Category category = categories.Add(
        categoryName,
        categoryColor,
        Outlook.OlCategoryShortcutKey.olCategoryShortcutKeyNone);
}

Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
mailItem.Categories = categoryName;
mailItem.Save();
```

Everything works if the user has 1 mailbox!
But, if the user has 2 mailboxes, and for example I process new messages in the second mailbox, then when I try to get a list of categories and check them, they will be from the session of the first mailbox! I.e. the event of clicking on the letter in the second mailbox and an attempt to process the `Application.Session.Categories;` returns categories from the first mailbox! How do I get the `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");` of the registered mailbox whose email I am currently processing?

**UPDATE 2**

*Dmitry Astreblechenko* - you are once again saving me with useful advice! But unfortunately I can't figure out how to properly process a hidden email?

```
Outlook.Stores st = _app.Session.Stores;
Outlook.MAPIFolder mf = st[1].GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.StorageItem stIt = mf.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.CategoryList", Outlook.OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);
///How to properly turn "stIt" into "Outlook.Categories" or get/change the data?
```

Comment: I use something like this: [Enumerate and add categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-enumerate-and-add-categories) . And it seems to me, maybe need to use it somehow, but I don't understand how: [Get information about multiple accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-information-about-multiple-accounts)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781490/get-the-list-of-outlook-categories-from-specific-account

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thank you for your advice! If this is true, then you will save me! :). Please tell me how to get the categories correctly and then read and write them? I updated my question and inserted a sample code.

Comment: As the post at the link above suggests, you need to use `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.getstorage?view=outlook-pia

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Updated the code in the question again ... Outlook.StorageItem stIt contains.
`Size - changing`
`LastModificationTime - It seems to be true`
`Subject - empty`
`Body - empty`
`UserProperties - empty`
`Attachment - empty`
But where to get the data?

Comment: Have you tried to look at that hidden message with Outlook Spy (go to the Calendar folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, double click on the "IPM.Configuration.CategoryList" item)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, I took advantage of your great addition! And I saw the necessary XML among the raw bytes ... i.e. the object `Outlook.StorageItem stIt` need to be processed as a RAW stream and parsed according to the `msg` format specification?

Comment: You will need to read the `PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C080102`) using `StorageItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. Since it is a binary property, you will get back a byte array, which you can convert to a string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thank you very much for giving me your attention and helping me understand the architecture of the system! Everything became approximately clear ... And I realized for myself that it is possible to get the categories of all profiles by going through the storage in the global session `_app.Session.Stores[1].Categories`. Ещё раз, большое спасибо и успехов Вам!

Answer (score 1):

All categories for coloring emails are stored in user profile repositories. You can process it like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checking color categories in all user profile repositories
/// </summary>
private void VerifyCategoryOnOutlook(string categoryName, Outlook.OlCategoryColor categoryColor)
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.Stores stores = _app.Session.Stores;
        Outlook.Categories currentCategories;
        bool isFound;
        foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
        {
            currentCategories = store.Categories;
            isFound = false;
            foreach (Outlook.Category category in currentCategories)
            {
                if (
                    category.Name == categoryName
                    & category.Color == categoryColor
                    )
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            //
            //Logic for processing categories when adding/editing
            //
            if (!isFound)
                AddCategoryOnOutlook(currentCategories, categoryName, categoryColor);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```